# How can you extract data from this json using, beautifulsoup and python?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

how can get those two values utc_last_updated and name given the following json ?
I used requests, to get to fetch the content, and then I used BeautifulSoup to make it like it is now. But now I just want to extract the two values that I have shown.

```
"data": [
        {
            "scm": "hg",
            "has_wiki": false,
            "last_updated": "2016-03-23T14:05:27.433",
            "no_forks": false,
            "created_on": "2016-03-18T22:55:52.705",
            "owner": "user",
            "email_mailinglist": "",
            "is_mq": false,
            "size": 420034,
            "read_only": false,
            "fork_of": null,
            "mq_of": null,
            "state": "available",
            "utc_created_on": "2016-03-18 21:55:52+00:00",
            "website": "",
            "description": "",
            "has_issues": false,
            "is_fork": false,
            "slug": "store",
            "is_private": true,
            "name": "store",
            "language": "python",
            "utc_last_updated": "2016-03-23 13:05:27+00:00",
            "no_public_forks": true,
            "creator": null,
            "resource_uri": "/1.0/repositories/my_url"
        },
        {
            "scm": "hg",
            "has_wiki": false,
            "last_updated": "2016-03-18T12:26:22.261",
            "no_forks": false,
            "created_on": "2016-03-18T12:19:08.262",
            "owner": "user",
            "email_mailinglist": "",
            "is_mq": false,
            "size": 173137,
            "read_only": false,
            "fork_of": null,
            "mq_of": null,
            "state": "available",
            "utc_created_on": "2016-03-18 11:19:08+00:00",
            "website": "",
            "description": "",
            "has_issues": false,
            "is_fork": false,
            "name": 'foo'
            "is_private": true,,
            "language": "python",
            "utc_last_updated": "2016-03-18 11:26:22+00:00",
            "no_public_forks": true,
            "creator": null,
            "resource_uri": "/1.0/repositories/my_rl"
        },
```

}
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this your full response? or did you get this from the HTML document?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have properly formatted JSON.

Comment: Hi, I'm following this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/18451025/how-to-hit-bitbucket-api-using-python-requests-module

Answer (score 4):

You've got a *`JSON` response*, not `HTML` - parse it with [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json

data = json.loads(response)
for item in data["data"]:
    print(item["utc_last_updated"])
```

Comment: I'm having this TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response'

Comment: @SlangI'mmatalk are you using `requests`? In this case, you might even do it like this: `data = response.json()`.

Comment: yes I'm using requests but when i'm doing this data = response.json(), the json is invalid. I'm following this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/18451025/how-to-hit-bitbucket-api-using-python-requests-module and after my requests.get I used beautifulsoup and then I want those values extraction.

Comment: @SlangI'mmatalk okay, what is exact value of `response.content` in your case?

Comment: the values that I have posted

Comment: @SlangI'mmatalk okay, what error does the `response.json()` produce exactly? (please edit the question and include the error traceback). Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107146/discussion-between-slang-imma-talk-and-alecxe).